# how to delete an entity in a one to one relation?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have two tables in my database in a one to one realtionship, is a weak relationship.

Videos(IDVideo, IDType, year, ...)
Serie(IDSerie, IDVideo, ...)

When I try to change the type of the video, if the new type is not a serie, I would like to delete the row in the series table that belongs to this video. So I follow this steps:

```
Videos myVideoDB = myContext.Videos.Include("Series").Where(v=>v.IDVideo == paramVideo.IDVideo).FirstOrDefault<Videos>();

myContext.Series.Remove(myVideoDB.Series.ElementAt(0));
```

in this second line I get the following error:

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'videos' of the relationship 'xxx' has the multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
```

Why? I think that when I delete the Serie, the DbContext knows  that it must delete the entity from the collection of Videos. Otherwise, I try to delete first the entity from the collection of videos and then delete the serie but the problem is not solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is that I need to delete the entity Series from the local in the DBContext:

```
long idSerie = miVideoDB.Series.ElementAt(0).IDSerie;
myVideoDB.Series.Clear();
miContexto.Series.Local.Remove(miContexto.Series.Local.FirstOrDefault<Series>(s => s.IDSerie == idSerie));
```

What I need is first get the ID of the serie, then clear the Series collection in my video and finllay delete the serie from the local.